# Disk boot failure, insert system disk and press Enter

Tags: hard-drive, boot, bios

Similar to [this related question](https://superuser.com/questions/93531/disk-boot-failure-insert-system-disk-and-press-enter), I came home and found that my media center pc showed this message,
`Disk boot failure, insert system disk and press Enter`

**Before I do anything with the (defective?) harddisk, what are the best first steps I can take to fix this with a minimum of damage?**

Normally the machine (Win Vista) is always on and never reboots by itself (Windows auto-updates are disabled too). Something must have caused it to reboot, though I'm sure we didn't have a power outage. The machine can't reboot on that disk, but it will boot on another disk I just plugged in for testing.

I haven't changed anything, or even touched the machine, for several days, and it has been running fine until now. I did replace the power supply some weeks ago, because the old one suddenly stopped working. It has been working fine with the replacement PSU.

Comment: I've unplugged the disk to make sure nothing more happens until I've learned some more. I've plugged in a spare disk and I'm installing Win7 on that, perhaps it will let me take a look at the defective disk.

Comment: Note: this solution worked for Windows Vista. I'm now using Windows 7 and have now the exact same problem again, but the Checkdisk utility (or command line tool) can't find any errors and doesn't fix the problem.
I'd expect that I could boot from the install disc and choose `restore`, but the install hangs before I get that far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by **booting from another harddisk with Windows and from there running the standard Windows Checkdisk utility on the defective disk with default settings.** That was all it took; I removed the replacement harddisk and was able to boot from the proper (now no longer defective) disk as usual.

It did require me to temporarily install a replacement disk and install Windows on that, so it took a while. But it worked - problem solved. I must admit that I still don't know what the *problem* actually was...

Comment: that message is what the BIOS says when it can't find boot code on the MBR.  maybe that was corrupted and just needed a little bit of chkdsk lovin'.... doesn't entirely make sense, but maybe the second-stage bootloader was what was having trouble, which seems more "fixable" by a basic chkdsk.  or maybe vista's chkdsk does MBR repairs by default now.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a silly answer, but make sure there's no USB drive plugged in that the computer is trying to boot from (and of course failing). I had this happen and felt migthy foolish when I figured it out...

Comment: We can rule that out. There's only 1 drive in the system, and nothing is connected via USB. Thanks for the quick suggestion though.

Comment: Then I would put the old drive in an external enclosure and hopefully rescue any valuable data, then depending on how critical this computer is I would just buy a new drive and do a clean install on that.

Comment: That would also have been my plan. I was hoping that another SuperUser could say how tomake the disk bootable again, so as to avoid a lot of new installation and so on. You know, just fix it. I'm afraid I'm going to have to start fresh instead of fixing...